# Creating exe file

Tags: vb.net, exe

I am trying to create an exe file that I can distribute to people but I was wondering if someone could explain to me if I write to a text file in my program and then create an exe will this crash when someone else downloads the app because I am pointing to a `c:user\source\programApp\repos\textfile.txt`

Is there a way to generically state textfile.txt in program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you should avoid writing a file to an absolute path.  Your users are generally unlikely to have the same path already existing on their systems, and you cannot be sure that your program will be run with sufficient priveleges to create the path, if it does not exist.

Instead you have three options:

1. Write your textfile.txt locally, i.e. in the same folder that the exe is.
2. Write your textfile.txt to a relative path, always being careful to check whether the path exists before writing to it (and attempting to create it first)
3. Write your textfile.txt to one of the standard user folders (or a sub-directory which you create, if necessary). To do this you use `System.Environment.GetFolderPath` passing it a relevant parameter, for instance `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments`

In all cases you should enclose the file writing in a `Try .. Catch` so that your program does not crash, if the exe is run with insufficient rights to write the file in the location specified.

Answer (score 1):

You should pretty much never hard-code a file or folder path. You should always use standard paths that are resolved at run time. You can use `Environment.GetFolderPath` or `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories` to get the paths of various standard Windows folders, including the user's Documents folder. Assuming that you're creating a Windows Forms or WPF app, you can use `Application.StartupPath` to get the folder that the current application was run from and then create file or subfolder paths from their using `Path.Combine` or `My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath`.

I should point out that normal users don't have permission to write under the Program Files folder, so writing to the application folder is generally a no-no.